# Drop a Dependent View in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I wonder ive landed myself up in an unusual problem of dropping all views and tables.
Tables dont have any primary key or foreign key relationship by default just that joined data has been shown through view. But after creating the view of joined tables i am unable to drop any view or table. I have tried both the ways to first drop table then view or vice versa nothing helped but the error shows cascade error even if theres no primary key or foreign key i know thats due to joined tables in view but how to drop them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can go - force the drop of the table or view where all dependent views will also be dropped OR map out the view dependencies.

For the first option just add CASCADE to the drop but be warned that more will be dropped than the table or view you list in the command.  So be sure this is really what you want to do.

The second option will take a little SQL but luckily someone has already written it (awslabs).  https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_view_dependency.sql  This SQL (as a view or as stand alone SQL) will list out the dependencies of which views are dependent on other views or tables.  You should be able to unwind things with this information.